# DynamoDb dax connection issue hadle exception in Node JS

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-dynamodb-dax, amazon-dynamodb-local

How we can handle exception getting from Dynamo Db DAX client in nodejs.I am using amazon-dax-client library.Also I want to redirect my request to Dynamo Db client if in case DAX Connection fails.

Below is the reference Code i am trying to achieve it

```
var ddbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ convertEmptyValues: true,maxRetries: 15 });
var daxClient: any = null;
if (process.env.ENDPOINT) {
  try {
    var dax = new AmazonDaxClient({
      endpoints: [process.env.ENDPOINT],
      region: Constants.AWS.REGION,
      maxRetries: 15
    });
    daxClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service: dax });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("eror",error)
  }
}
 this.client = daxClient != null ? daxClient : ddbClient;
```

Comment: What's the exception?